# Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class error when using JTextField

Tags: java, swing, variables, compiler-errors, jtextfield

I have spent hours searching and I cannot figure out how to fix this. Maybe I'm just completely off, but I keep getting the error "Cannot refer to a non-final variable userInput inside an inner class defined in a different method". IF somebody could help me figure out why this occurs or how to fix it, that would be appreciated.

I get 2 compilation errors:
Cannot refer to a non-final variable userInput inside an inner class defined in a different method

and

Cannot refer to a non-final variable inputField inside an inner class defined in a different method

EDIT: Some clarification, I want to keep my userInput variable as not final.

Here's my code, maybe somebody can see what I'm doing wrong, I've omitted all the code that has nothing to do with this error:

```
//Import libraries
...
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
...

public class TextGame {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    ...  
    String userInput = "Input";
    ...

    // Create the window
    JFrame gameWindow = new JFrame("Game");
    gameWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gameWindow.setVisible(true);
    // Centre the window
    gameWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    ...

    // Add input box to window
    JTextField inputField = new JTextField();
    inputField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            userInput = inputField.getText(); ****Here is where the error occurs***
        }
    });

    gameWindow.add(inputField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // Size the window to what it contains
    gameWindow.pack();
    ...


}
}
```

Comment: `userInput` is a variable local to `main`.  It has to be an instance or static (class) member before Java will let you modify it from anywhere but the context of `main`.  In this case, you can just make it a field on `TextGame` (static or instance, depending on whether you intend to have an instance of the class).

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question:

```
final JTextField inputField = new JTextField();
```

However, a better solution is to access the text field from the ActionEvent:

```
JTextField textField =  (JTextField)e.getSource();
userInput = textField.getText();
```

Comment: When I do this, I still get the error on the variable though. Even if I change the variable to final, I then get the error The final local variable userInput cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at your code too closely. The problem is that you are trying to build your GUI in the main method. Instead you should be creating a custom class that extends JPanel. Then you can define class level varaiables (like userInput). Then you just add the panel to a JFrame. Take a look at the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html). Download the demo and structure your program like the demo code.

Comment: Alright, I was hoping to not do that, but it seems that I must. Will change, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access your variable "userInput" outside a class or method other than where it was declared, you cannot do this unless it's prefixed with the keyword "final" so that the scope of the variable is extended.
eg. final String userInput;

Comment: Ok, but I need the variable to not be final. Is there any way to go about getting around this while still having the variable not be final?

Comment: Its the text field that you need to make final, not the String variable.

Comment: When I make the text field final, I get an error that the variable must then be final.

Comment: declare it globally in the class, then you need not use the final qualifier

Answer (score 0):

You are creating instance of inner anonymous class ActionListener. If such classes uses variables from parent class all such variables should be marked as final. That is because such variables are *copied* into autogenerated constructor of inner class. To avoid uncoordinated changes of copies they should be constant.